# Printing multiple objects without spaces

Tags: python, printing, reverse, spaces

I'm writing a basic program to convert any 4 digit number in reverse.

I know I'm taking a very complex approach, but that's what my professor requires. So far I've got:

```
print("This program will display any 4-digit integer in reverse order")

userNum = eval(input("Enter any 4-digit integer: "))

num1 = userNum % 10

userNum2 = userNum // 10

num2 = userNum2 % 10

userNum3 = userNum // 100

num3 = userNum3 % 10

userNum4 = userNum // 1000

num4 = userNum4 % 10

print(num1,num2,num3,num4)
```

The issue I'm having is the output from the print statement gives me

```
x x x x
```

When I would prefer to have

```
xxxx
```

Any advice?

Comment: `print("{}{}{}{}".format(num1, num2, num3, num4))`, `print("%s%s%s%s" % (num1, num2, num3, num4))` or others.

Comment: Use `print('%d%d%d%d'%(num1,num2,num3,num4))` or `print('{}{}{}{}'.format(num1,num2,num3,num4))`.

Comment: try this: `print(''.join([ str(k) for k in [num1,num2,num3,num4] ]))`

Comment: Don't use `eval` when your intent is to create an `int` object; use `int`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read the description of the [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#print), you can see that you can change your last line for:

```
print(num1,num2,num3,num4, sep='')
```

Comment: That works perfectly, hopefully that will be acceptable by my prof as I do believe we covered formatting. Thank you!

Comment: If you think my answer is appropriate can you consider accepting the answer ? https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

Since you just want to convert the input in reverse order. You can take the following approach.

```
print("This program will display any 4-digit integer in reverse order")
userNum = input("Enter any 4-digit integer: ")
reverse_input = userNum[::-1]
reverse_input = int(reverse_input) # If you want to keep input as an int class
print(reverse_input)
```

If you want to use your own code then just change the print statement.

```
print(str(num1) + str(num2) + str(num3) + str(num4))
```

String concatenation does not add space so you should get desired result.

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate all your help guys!

Answer (score 0):

I used this as a sort of exercise for myself to nail down loops. There are a few loops you can use.

```
#if using python <3
from __future__ import print_function

x = 3456

z = x

print('While:')

while z > 0:
    print(z % 10, end="")
    z = z / 10;

print()
print('For:')

for y in xrange(4):
    z=x%10
    print(z, end="")
    x = x / 10
```

Thanks for asking this question. It encouraged me to go look at python syntax, myself, and I think it's a good exercise.